# Druapl 7 Update list_text in content type

Tags: drupal-7

I have a custom content type setup in Drupal.
I have a field that gets created with a type of list_text.

When I install the module everything works great. However when someone creates a page with that content type I need to dynamiclly update the values of the list whenever someone creates a new page of that content type.

I am new to Drupal so any help would be great. I have tried hook_alter_form hook_alter_FORM_ID (please excuse  me those may not be the right names typing from memory)

Thank you so much.

Brandon

Comment: What type of changes do you want to do to that list?

Answer (score 0):

do some think like this in custom module

```
function ModuleName_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  if($form_id == "list_text") {
    $form['#submit'][] = 'list_text_node_submit';
  }

}
function list_text_node_submit($form, &$form_state){

  $getvalue = $form_state['values']['fieldName']['und'][0]['value'];//get value from node
  $form_state['values']['someOtherField']['und'][0]['value'] = "some thing"; // set new value

}
```

hope this helps